# Mixed MySQL and Sphinx queries

Tags: mysql, subquery, sphinx

I have MySQL and Sphinx installed and working properly on a LNMP server. Now I'd like to integrate a Sphinx sub-query into an existing MySQL query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql_table
JOIN (SELECT id FROM sphinx_index MATCH ('keyword')) AS match_table
ON match_table.id = mysql_table.id
```

Is this possible? If not, should I do the Sphinx separately and then use `WHERE IN` in the MySQL query, or will this kill the extra efficiency I'm getting from Sphinx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SphinxSE
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse-overview

Then would be

```
SELECT * FROM mysql_table
JOIN (SELECT id FROM sphinx_index WHERE query='keyword') AS match_table
ON match_table.id = mysql_table.id
```

Although

```
SELECT * FROM sphinx_index INNER JOIN mysql_table USING (id) WHERE query='keyword'
```

is shorter and more concise. **And** better maintains the order of results.

Where 'sphinx_index' is a SphinxSE table, which points to underlying sphinx index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the answer on another SO question:

[Integrating Sphinx to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698223/integrating-sphinx-to-mysql)

From reading this, it looks like Sphinx and MySQL are not as integrated as I had hoped. They need to be used on separate connections, so you can't combine queries. Oh well...

Comment: That's talking about SphinxQL. SphinxSE **would** allow you to run a query like your example. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse-overview