# Subqueries with sphinx and mysql

Tags: subquery, sphinx

[Link to similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666322/mixed-mysql-and-sphinx-queries)

Let's say i have a query something like this :

```
'SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM bla WHERE name ='Mr.Anderson')'
```

Usually you write in sphinx.config main part of query, which gets data, and indexes it... And then you with php sphinx api  , set different filters to get what you want....

As i already understood sphinx can't work with subqueries... Something like SphinxSE exists for that purpose , or at least it can handle subqueries , but

**(**SphinxSE is just an ordinary client that talks to searchd over network. You need it when you do not have a native API for your language and want to work through MySQL. Or if you want to optimize certain workloads that pull big Sphinx result sets directly to MySQL and additionally process them there (and avoid overheads of pulling Sphinx set to application and then immediately pushing it to MySQL).**)**

So my question is if i will start using sphinxSE will i still be able to use php sphinx api , with those subqueries? And i would really appreciate if you could give maybe **tutorials or articles** with examples about this whole story , how to do it..

And second question is , what are my other options , if i won't use SphinxSe....

For example i write 2 different sources and indexes , one for subquery , other for main query and then just through filter insert subquery results into query through php sphinx api ....  Is this big overhead for something like this or not ?

Thx in advance...

Comment: The bigger question is what exactly do you mean by 'subquery' - what are you trying to DO?

Comment: @barryhunter I don't really understand what you mean , but you are right, i made a mistake in explaining. Basically Mr.Anderson should be '?' , which is inserted after user submits form. In sql it is  one query , where you insert data and get the response. But with sphinx i guess you can't do it like this . Instead i need to index data from table bla , filter it by user name in this case Mr.Anderson . And then index data i table blabla and filter it by data a got from table bla. And it feels like overhead , so i am wondering can i do something like  sphinxSE suggests doing ->>>

Comment: SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE query='test;index=test1;';  but only with php sphinx api... or SphinxSE and php sphinx api ..... Because like i understand it even if i install sphinxSE and would be able to do it, then php sphinx api would usless , and i am not even sure how i would be able to integrate it in php ... And how much more complicated it would become without api... But i haven't tried it to be honest... So i am asking if it is even possible to something like this or not.

Comment: I still say you need to go back to basis. Dont focus on sub-queries. Focus on what your eventual task is. Its quite probably subqueries, are not the right tool for the job. What type of searches are you trying to run? What (mysql) tables do you have, what sphinx index(s). In your current example, have no idea wat 'bla' is.

Comment: @barryhunter I am not sure if i am allowed to post samples of code , because it's a big project , with lots of models, and i work work for people who do it, but does it really matter?

The big question is what is the right way to search with sphinx if in query you use is sub-query.  Take for example this first example from here http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/writing-subqueries.shtml, where SELECT * FROM Client WHERE C_ID IN (SELECT C_ID FROM Products); is query.  
How would search it with sphinx?  If it was only SELECt * FROM Client , would be easy. You would just index all data,

Comment: in sphinx.conf , set attributes for filtering , and with php api ->setFilters for limiting the options , and maybe even search some string .... But here in query you basically have 2 queries. So what would you do and how would you do it ?

Comment: If i understand correctly what you are trying to say is that maybe sub-queries is the wrong way  to do it , and you should avoid them, restructure the tables, and the query itself , and then everything will be ok, but what if it is the right way , or i can't change it.... What is the aproach to deal with things like this aka sub-queries.  Oh and , sorry i again brought a bad example , in sub-query should be some data which is undefined till the submission , something like  SELECT * FROM Client WHERE C_ID IN (SELECT C_ID FROM Products WHERE something = ?);

Comment: I point is, because you refuse to give details, we cant really say what would be the best way. Its like asking a machanic to help fix your car, but refuse to let him/her actully see the car. Still not sure how you intend to use sub-queries, I think can honestly say that have never used sub-queries in conjunction with sphinx - there is simply no need.