# Can Lucene, Sphinx (or any other engine) index binary data?

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, sphinx

I already have a Sql Server 2008 based app in production, where am using Full text search by storing the binary (along with the file extension). Which means the same column can store doc, xls, pdf, docx... etc. I went for that approach (knowing it would be insert costly) because i have varied files which can be uploaded and I don't want to run into madness of converting text from various types (xls, xlsx, doc, docx, pdf etc) of files. Also i am not aware of any free tools which can do that for me. I don't want to use filesystem as that would be insecure and maintenance will be costly.

> **Now am looking for the ease (or difficulty) to move to mysql. Do have some options of full text search in mysql For ex: MySql Full text
>   search (which does not index binary), Sphinx and Solr.**

I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698223/integrating-sphinx-to-mysql), which is kind of closest to what i need... Although i guess Sphinx doesn't index binary data... However, by using SphinxSE i can query the mysql tables and Sphinx to get related resultset (in the same connection). I hope that understanding is correct. But am not sure of the performance. **Can someone add more insight?**

Of what i have heard... Integrating Lucene with Mysql is difficult.

> **My need is to fetch ranked results based on criterion which can be structured (stored in RDBMS) and unstructured (textual dats which
>   shall be indexed).**

Also, is there any other option which looks like more suitable in my given situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ElasticSearch (uses lucene under the hood like Solr) I think it may do what you require I haven't needed document indexing though so not tried it.

See here though for more information

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-attachment-type.html

It uses Apache Tika to convert the documents to indexable content (same as SQL server does with IFilter plugins)

Comment: You confirmed my thoughts, i did discuss with one my friends and he also suggested the same... actually its exactly (almost) how Sql Server text search works. Now the only question left is to integrate with MySql, will it be a good idea? for combining Structured and Text search.

Or,

You suggest to store all the data in a structured format and index through elastic search? Guess that's possible too. Its just that this would be insert/update heavy...

Am also thinking of taking a radical shift and move to Mongo DB, am hopeful elastic search will integrate it well with that too.

Comment: well the documents you add to ElasticSearch should contain a back reference but usually you index everything you might need into the same document as separate fields.  So in theory you don't need to back link to the existing data.  But if you did need to combine results like SphinxSE does you can do it on a page per page but not a full join.

Comment: sorry missed some of your comment.  mongodb is supported using rivers https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/

Comment: Thanks for all the information... I believe this is a good kick start for my POC...

Also, will MongoDB would be too early to move to? Although i see lot of companies using MongoDB in production.

Comment: I have to do these test my self on MongoDB I am going to be setting up an MongoDB + ElasticSearch environment as well.  But MongoDB is production ready so I see no reason not to test in a POC environment thats what a POC is for ;)

Comment: I will keep a tab on you... :D You look to me the person of great help in future ;)
Will keep you posted about the POC progress!